# How to return the index of child in Layout?

Tags: android, get, indexing, android-linearlayout

I have the following situation - HorizontalScrollView (HSV), inside HSV - LinearLayout and inside it number of buttons - the code is here:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Footer"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:background="@drawable/footer_bg"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hsvLinearLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/today"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/today"
                android:drawablePadding="0sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:text="@string/today"
                android:onClick="getRSSNews"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/life"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/life"
                android:drawablePadding="0sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:text="@string/life"
                android:onClick="getRSSNews"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/corner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/corner"
                android:drawablePadding="0sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:text="@string/corner"
                android:onClick="getRSSNews"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/banks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/banks"
                android:drawablePadding="0sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:text="@string/banks"
                android:onClick="getRSSNews"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/it"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/it"
                android:drawablePadding="0sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:text="@string/it"
                android:onClick="getRSSNews"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fun"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/fun"
                android:drawablePadding="0sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:text="@string/fun"
                android:onClick="getRSSNews"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Is there a way to get the position(index) of the button, on which has been clicked!

Answer (score 83):

[indexOfChild](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#indexOfChild%28android.view.View%29) returns the position in the group of the specified child view.

Comment: Thanks, I just have to use a ViewGroup!

Answer (score 6):

You may give tag to each view and check the tag when that view is clicked.This may help you.

Comment: It doesn't help me. I do not need to specify a tag for each view, i could use the ID, but I already figure it out, thanks to xevincent.